# How can I set automatically the value in text field with a drop down?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I automatically show the Day in the text when choose in the drop down options using the .attr() in jquery?

This is my HTML code:

```
<select id="time">
<option day="M-W-F">07:00 - 08:00 am</option>
<option day="T-Th">08:30 - 10:00 am</option>
<option day="Saturday">7:00 - 10:00 am</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="day" placeholder="Day" />
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#time").on('change', function(){
    $("#day").val() == $("#time").val().attr('day');
   })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to to pass the value to `.val()` method and use `:selected` to target the selected `option` then use `.attr()`

```
$("#day").val($("#time option:selected").attr('day'))
```

I would recommend you to use `data-*` custom attributes to store arbitrary data

```js
$("#time").on('change', function() {
  $("#day").val($("#time option:selected").data('day'))
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="time">
<option data-day="M-W-F">07:00 - 08:00 am</option>
<option data-day="T-Th">08:30 - 10:00 am</option>
<option data-day="Saturday">7:00 - 10:00 am</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="day" placeholder="Day" />
```

Comment: Good suggestion for the `data` attributes. I was wondering about making a comment about this on the question ^^.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Additional notes

> Because :selected is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :selected cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :selected to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":selected").

jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#time").on('change', function(){
     $("#day").val($("#time option:selected").attr('day'))
   })
})
</script>
```